# Looking for a canonical answer to web development language relationships and flow

Tags: discussion, canonical

Over and over between PHP and JavaScript questions I see a lot of question askers who don't understand the difference between server-side and client-side code. I would really like to see a good answer explaining the difference between PHP, JavaScript, CSS, HTML, when they run and how they run and how they relate to each other.

It'd be really nice to be able to refer these poor misguided souls to information within this site explaining that no, you can't [call a jQuery function from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928602/calling-a-jquery-function-from-php/) or [call a PHP function from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405017/call-a-php-command-from-javascript) -- and many other crazy things of a similar nature, see, this is how the technology/languages relate, and interact; please read up on it!

Is there such a question/answer somewhere? If there is no such question, how would I go about wording such a question to meet the standards of this site? I know the subject in general is quite broad but I think that a good answer should be possible -- I, for one, would find it useful, if only to help people understand what they are doing!

Comment: So, would it be need to be longer than "client-side code runs on the client and server-side code runs on the server"?

Comment: haha I get tired of posting that over and over again. It'd be nice to have things explained in a little more detail so they understand what is "client-side" and what is "server-side" and how they relate to eachother

Comment: I disagree @derp.  Many people have issues doing an ajax call to a php script, and jumbling the call, or handling the response incorrectly.  Or perhaps they formed the response wrong on the PHP script?  While there's a world of difference between client-side and server-side scripts, the two often depend on each other and interact together.  Many good questions can, and should, be tagged with both.

Comment: Behold! The next level of this question topic can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667965/use-yii2-inside-sailsjs). Should we write a new, somehow broader question of this one?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here's a canonical question/answer explaining the difference between client-side and server-side: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programmin)

Comment: That is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for! Bookmarked and ready to use :)

Comment: The wonderful reviewers have looked at the examples I posted and flagged them as duplicates, the originals have great answers worth posting here, to give more detail on some of the specifics: [How to call a javascript function from php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php) and [How to call a php function from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

As those two questions you linked to have answer now you can use them as canonical duplicate targets.

Basically everytime you run into a question that confuses server- and client-side you close vote if flag to close as a duplicate of one the canonical questions.

Example of such questions exist:

[What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
[What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)