# What are the limits for self-answers? When are they (not) acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope, self-answer

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27229589/1207195). It's a *fake* question used as an umbrella for a long answer where I tried to collect many common issues about Unicode text management and globalization stuff.

In my intention it had to be a generic self-answered question to be used as general guidance to begin a deeper study of the topic and to dupe close all almost similar questions (*Which code page for non-Unicode file names in [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) files?* or *In C#, how can I count* characters *in a string?*).

To me it seems perfectly reasonable and there are many examples (also few from me), but **this** question received (well also its self-answer even if they should be unrelated) some downvotes and **four** close votes which makes me think I may be wrong. One user pointed to this meta question: [Can you answer your own questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250204/1207195) where accepted answer states that:

> This is not a place to post a blog so make sure that the question/answer is general enough to be helpful to other members, but not so broad that it doesn't target a specific programming issue.

So my question is: is this self-answered question too "blog post"y to be useful and should it simply be deleted (no matters how many times I'll have to copy & paste paragraphs from it)?

**More in general**: I would like to know if this kind of *umbrella* questions can be *bad* questions, because their value come from question and answer, together, like evergreen Saunder's question [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1207195). Obviously, the question alone is *terrible*, but it's valuable (and highly upvoted), because it's a great highly used reference.

**Reasoning**: I like to see Stack Overflow not only as a *patches repository* or a long list of *footnotes* to MSDN, MDN, man pages, javadoc and so on. Is it a *quick fix my problem site*? In my mind it has to be a **knowledge repository**, a **learning resource** then a broad question and a long post are welcome if they are general enough to help someone else.

I can't understand: with hundred answers that, for example, suggests C# string length is the number of characters in the text (even highly [upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23369865/1207195) and [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5141900/1207195), propagating this misconception with no mention it's *wrong*)...we worry if a question is too broad and/or good by itself? Really? Are these things relegated to our blogs and Stack Overflow is a place for half-working solutions where you need great time to pick a little bit better one? I think very [specific real-world questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15980310/1207195) are (rare) pearls, but they're hard to find and longer to understand: *I'm searching solution for X, this post talks about Y, move on*. <del>**EDIT** question has been closed, reopened then closed again...I'm still waiting feedback here on meta (answers/comments), but I start to think I've been just pretty unlucky when I saw posts I linked (and many others) then I should simply delete that bad (because too broad) useless (because everyone knows and judging by votes the answer is also completely wrong) question...</del>

I can't see official *guidance* and then I would collect some feedback on meta, **what do users want**? **What's the Stack Overflow team's direction** about this? What should I do? Stop doing this? Downvoting and closing each post like this I see on Stack Overflow? Is a C# FAQ (similar to [C++ FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252874/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag) that exists on Stack Overflow) a bad idea?

Comment: What actually bothers me most about the question is not whether it's appropriate for the site or if the question and answer justify one another. It's the fact that "UNICODE" is so consistently capitalized throughout the entire thing. I'm not sure where you got the idea that Unicode was an acronym that stood for anything. It's not. Even the multiple quotations that you include in your self-answer, in which it's *not* capitalized, suggest otherwise.

Comment: @BoltClock your diamond is UNICODE ;)

Comment: @boltclock I can't stop to see it not as acronym but as abbreviation so,  no matters how hard I try, I always   write it "small-capped"! Anyway you're right, it pretends to be a _word_ then thanks for your patient editing!!!

Comment: Now "small-capped" is bothering me even more than "UNICODE." ;p

Comment: i will never understand why i so often see people put certain words in all-caps for seemingly no reason. does anyone get why people do this?

Comment: @sgroves to _speak_ loudly, very often, but also to _simulate_ small-caps for acronyms and some abbreviations...

Comment: yeah but i mean words that aren't acronyms or abbreviations (like unicode).

Comment: sort of typewriter style EMPHASIS ;)

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. please don't do that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my intention it had to be a generic self-answered question to be
>   used as general guidance to begin a deeper study of the topic and to
>   dupe close all almost similar questions (*which code page for
>   non-Unicode file names in zip files? or in C# how can I count
>   characters in a string?*).

I agree generally with the answers already given [by Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278209/2359271) and [by musefan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278214/2359271) – this isn't a good platform for the breadth of guidance your question and answer aimed to provide. I want to address the other motivation you identified, which was providing a *canonical* Q&A to use when closing other questions as duplicates.

There are several discussions about canonical questions and answers here on meta, including:

- [Is there a canonical question telling people why they should use SQL parameters?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272881/2359271)
- [Is there a canonical duplicate for `to_string` questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276841/2359271)
- [Looking for a canonical answer to web development language relationships and flow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269305/2359271)

Each implicitly assumes that using an existing question is better than creating a new one. If you don't know of an appropriate canonical target, that doesn't mean it doesn't exist; and if it doesn't exist, there may still be a question that's close enough that it could be edited to fit that role.

If there's no canonical target, it's a *big job* to create one, whether you're transforming an existing question or starting from scratch. The best thing to do, as soon as you found yourself thinking about writing what you called a "fake" question, would have been to run your idea past the meta community first. [Canonical duplicate for "floating point is inaccurate"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260130/2359271) is one example of how this can work. The guidance you would have received from such a discussion would have helped you avoid the breadth issues that got your question closed in the first place.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer, I think a canonical answer was needed (especially because well...I didn't find any both _accepted_ and right answer) but the way to go was to ask on meta first, I admit I didn't even think to first discuss on meta, I posted here after discussion started on question comments. Also thanks for links to other related posts.

Answer (score 31):

Your question is going to be held up to the same standards as every single other question asked on this site.  The fact that you want to answer it yourself changes nothing about how the question should be evaluated, just as the fact that you asked the question does nothing to change how the answer should be evaluated.

If you want to self answer a question both the question and the answer *both* need to be quality posts that meet all of the site's standards.

---

As to your specific question, yes, it is most certainly *way* too broad.  It's asking to learn everything about localization in every single language.  That's **way** beyond the scope of an appropriate SO question.  You even state right in the question in the first revision that it's a huge topic that cannot be covered in an answer here.  Clearly *you yourself* feel that the question was Too Broad when you asked it.

Comment: Isn't this in constrast with, for example, other "dupe catching" questions like [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1207195) (and _brothers_)? Value there is not in question itself (too broad and without _effort_) but in answer(s) used as reference for future readers...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti That question can be answered, reasonably completely, in a handful of paragraphs.  All of the differences between each of the hundreds of NRE questions are very rarely germane to the question at hand.  You're asking to list out *everything* about localisation.  There's no way you can provide all of that in a few paragraphs.  Entire books are written on the subject, making it they very definition of Too Broad.  There's no way that you can provide a quality answer to that in a few paragraphs, and no way that such a post would be a suitable duplicate target for other questions.

Comment: So, if I understand what you mean, question+answer problem is that question is _too broad_, it can't be a _catch all_ similar questions, it should be more focused on a specific issue (even if in this way someone won't read it even if it may be appropriate to his case). Well then I suppose also multi-language tags aren't appropriate (even if general discussion is pretty language agnostic).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The question is evaluated no differently as a result of you answering it; that's the simplest way to understand what you need to do.  The question should be a great question that you would want to ask or see someone else ask even if you weren't posting an answer along with it.  If you wouldn't want to see someone post the same question that you have without the answer, then you shouldn't be posting it.

Comment: That makes me more confused! [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1207195) is a question+answer I upvoted (and I'm not alone!) because of their value together. Question itself (without its self-answer) deserves downvotes and to be closed (unfortunately original comments have been deleted). However I agree with you when you say _"You're asking to list out everything about localisation. There's no way you can provide all of that in a few paragraphs."_. That makes sense, question (even umbrella question) can't be such broad.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti What about it is confusing?  If you want to ask a question, it needs to be a good question; you shouldn't be asking a garbage question, and if you do it anyway, you shouldn't be surprised when people provide feedback that it's a bad question.  If you want people to treat it as a good question then **ask a good question**.

Comment: Because, let me repeat: _"...[this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1207195) is a question+answer I upvoted (and I'm not alone!) because of **their value together**. Question itself (without its self-answer) deserves downvotes..."_. That question is **obviously** not a good question but it has a great value together with its answer (because it'll help many users search for _NullReferenceException_ and it's perfect to close 1M dups).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti You may *want* that to be the case, but that's not how the site works.  You need to ask a question that is appropriate *on its own*.  The fact that you want to answer a question when asking it doesn't magically mean you're allowed to violate all of the rules of the site that determine what makes a good question.  The question needs to be appropriate on its own.  Yours is not.  It was closed entirely correctly for a reason that applies exactly.  It was downvoted for reasons that are entirely appropriate.  If you have a problem with that then *ask a good question*.

Comment: is it a rainy gray day there? I'm asking this on meta exactly to understand _rules_, especially because there are great examples (and I don't mean my question is one of them) where *your opinion* isn't supported by many of us (in question I'm using as example there are *411 upvotes* and 25 downvotes). Maybe I've not been clear but purpose of this question on meta is to understand if: "is it appropriate to post a _stupid_ question to give a generic enough answer and to use it to close as dups many other similar/future _stupid_ questions"? I see, _you_ think it's not.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Why are you asking the question if you're merely going to reject any answers you get as someone having a bad day.  You've gotten the answer to your question.  Apparently you don't like it, but it's the answer, and you'll see it replicated all across the many questions on the topic.  If you want to keep asking bad questions you can; I can't stop you, but you shouldn't complain about your questions getting closed or downvoted when you ask questions that **you freely admit are bad**.  I wish I could stop you from knowingly asking bad questions, but I cannot.

Comment: Well, it *is* a rainy gray day every day here on meta.

Comment: It isn't Servy's opinion, it is the rule of the site. All questions are treated equal and held up to the same standards irrespective of answers and answerers.

Comment: I don't _want_ to ask bad questions and for sure I will not ask them to provide self-answers if I'll have feedback on meta that this isn't what Q&A style is for (then yes, you may stop me to do it if your opinion is shared by many people). BTW I wasn't _complaining_ but maybe my English can't express the concept or you're to used to see users ranting about downvotes...

Comment: @BoltClock let's change meta's theme to a peaceful green...

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I thought it is for one year then I saw appreciated and useful questions which are not and then I thought rules are relaxed in that case. Now I'm here to ask official guidance...

Comment: @Servy, maybe it's me but you seem to be ignoring AdrianoRepetti's question. His question restated. Why is [this question which is a bad question by your definition](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1207195) not closed? You claim bad questions should be closed. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1207195) is a bad question. Why is it not closed? He's arguing the only reason [this bad question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1207195) is not closed is because of the answers. He believes if there were no answers it would be closed as a bad question.

Comment: @gman There are lots of bad questions that don't get closed.  Just because some questions that merit closure don't get enough attention to get closed doesn't mean other bad questions can't be closed, it just means that there are more people asking close-worthy questions than there are people willing and able to close them, so some will slip through.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't help us know what's a good question if we see questions like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1207195) not closed. So then people try to copy the clearly highly voted example since by having high votes and not being closed it's clearly an example of what the site wants and accepts, only then to be told no, they're doing it wrong.

Comment: @gman I don't disagree that having questions meriting closure not closed is a problem.  The real question is how to solve it though.

Answer (score 15):

To start with, I just want to say I am fully of the belief that questions should be judged by the existing standards, and not your "good intentions". And in that respect - as I did with my close vote - I believe the question is too broad.

Now to focus a bit on why I believe your "good intentions" are wrong...

The majority of visitors on SO are people searching for a solution to a specific problem. Take your examples for (erm...) example:

If people just want to know `"which code page for non-Unicode file names in zip files?"` and they stumble across your long-winded post, then how to you expect that to help them? Do you really think they will want to read/learn everything about Unicode just to solve their issue? No, I think they will want the quick fix approach.

But given your ideal world of concatenating all short specific questions in to one "catch all", you would lose that ability to find quick solutions to simple problems. And that - in my opinion - would take away what makes SO such a great resource in the first place.

Speaking personally: I don't come to SO to learn in any great detail. I come here to either find a quick solution to my problems, or to help return some solutions to the community that has helped me so often.

Bottom line, as interesting and in-depth as your answer is, I just don't think it serves any benefit being here. It's a blog post and should live on a blog. Maybe SO should support blogs/articles (which a dedicated area), but that's for another day.

Comment: LOL we had to _meet_ again on meta! I have to say I highly agree with this sentence: _"But ... concatenating all short specific questions ... you would lose that ability to find quick solutions to simple problems..."_. Maybe you're right about this even if I wouldn't like to see SO as a _flash_ patches sites but a knowledge repository.

Comment: Why is UNICODE uppercase? [BoltClock will not like it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278206/which-are-limits-for-self-answers-when-they-are-not-acceptable#comment123550_278206)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: I was just going with the flow

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think that stack overflow is an inappropriate place for your answer. You said yourself, "It's a fake question used as an umbrella for a long answer where I tried to collect many common issues about Unicode text management and globalization stuff." That's not how this should work, a blog would have been the perfect place to put something like that. Or even a site where you could submit articles or some other small publications.