# Downvoting of self-answered question (aka "share your knowledge")

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Last week I faced a problem which took me several hours to analyze. Today I pondered whether I should share my insights since it would take a considerable amount of my work time. [I decided for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232539/missingmanifestresourceexception-when-accessing-resource-wrapper-for-resx-file) because I wanted to give back to the SO community. The question immediately attracted two downvotes. One of them (I suppose) gave a reason that hinted that he didn't really care enough to read the question but cared enough to downvote it. Being "punished" (a bit of a harsh word) for sharing one's knowledge really feels wrong. I guess I'm a bit butthurt. :)

So I guess my question is: Is this just what one has to put up with? Is this simply the prize we have to pay? Just an ugly little downside of a voting system that otherwise works great?

Comment: Gave you an upvote there, seems like a rather obscure error to me.

Answer (score 6):

That question deserved some downvotes.

Self-answered questions (and the answers!) are still held to the quality standards of the site.

I see several problems with the question right away:

1. No actual question was asked, you just posted the error message
2. The code that generated the error message is not present

Make the question a *good* SO question, and the upvotes you want will come.

Related: [What are the limits for self-answers? When are they (not) acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278206/which-are-limits-for-self-answers-when-they-are-not-acceptable)

Comment: As an aside; the answer was pretty good. Please do work on the question though.

Comment: Alright, I wasn't aware that I have to make up a question when I already know the answer to the problem. I've added the two points you've noted. Personally I don't really see how it adds much of value. Do you think it does? I think people should ask themselves: "Would I be thankful if I found this question if I had the same problem?". If the answer is "yes" it means it adds something of value. I think the mentality here drives contributors away.

Comment: @user232986 Call me pedantic, but yes, I think the changes add a *ton* of value (though I'm not sure I believe your sample code is valid C#). Granted, the content is much the same, but you actually *asked a question*. I'm not saying it couldn't be better, but it also wasn't terrible to begin with (-2 isn't that much, especially with the answer upvotes). Here's an article you may find interesting (and relevant): http://blog.codinghorror.com/how-to-write-without-writing/

Comment: I can see your point. Another argument for it would be that other users should also be able to add answers. Without an actual question this becomes harder. Another point I want to add (after reading your link): Downvoters should also keep in mind that many (maybe even most) SO users are not native speakers. It takes a lot of effort to formulate a post in a foreign language one doesn't use every day. That is often a reason why a question or answer lacks clarity. If it's interesting anyway one should consider improving the grammar etc. instead of downvoting it. (OT: What's wrong with my code?)

Comment: @user232986 I will *never* downvote on grammar alone (unless it makes it completely unreadable), and I try to leave a comment if I downvote (and I'll always come back if you ping me!) I'm not saying all SO users all like that, but I think most voters really do want to see the content improved. To the code, without any other context, the `Resource.Key` seems like it wouldn't be correct (based on C# naming conventions and known class names). It *could* be, but I'd have to see the `Resource` declaration.

Comment: You give very constructive feedback, my criticism wasn't targeted at you! :) I didn't get downvoted very often but when I did I rarely got feedback. The `Resource` class is the wrapper I was talking about further above. It is generated by Visual Studio/ResGen. `Key` is the static property which returns the value of the resource called `Key`.

Comment: @user232986 Fair enough. Tip: Don't call a resource "Key". Its really confusing when every resource should *have* a "Key". In fact, avoid using standard C# property/class names as variable names in general.