# I cannot nominate a question for reopening twice? Even if it has been closed and reopened again?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-reopen

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27229589/1207195) (mine) question has been closed then reopened (I also nominated for reopening) then closed again (in case you're interested [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278206/1207195) is meta post about that, also closed and reopened). I just tried to cast a *reopen* vote again but a message told me I can't because I *already* voted to reopen that question. Yes, I did, but after that question has been reopened and closed again!

Why that *applied* vote still count? Is this by-design to prevent close/reopen wars or is it a bug? I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252584/1207195) post (and linked posts) and help pages but I can't find anything related to this issue.

(I tagged this question with [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug), let me know if [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) is more appropriate).

Comment: It's by design. To prevent close/reopen wars.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On any given post, you can vote to close once, and vote to reopen once. This is to prevent close/reopen wars.

If you edited your question, it will be put into the reopen queue of course, so it will get some consideration.

From the "Close Vote Privilige" help page:

> Questions can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, but each
>   individual user may only vote once in each direction in the cycle.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: Thank you! I read that "cycle" as a single run of a set ("cycles"). :| have to improve my english. 9 minutes to accept

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti After reading it again, I agree the wording could be improved!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Posted a request to correct the wording: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278294/please-correct-the-close-privilege-help-page

Comment: However, moderators are allowed to reopen questions several times. Proof: Martijn Pieters♦, Sklivvz♦ and bluefeet♦ have, at the time I'm writing this, each reopened [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) twice (see the [edit history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/342440/revisions)).