# Please correct the close-privilege help-page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, help-center

The [close-privilege help-page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) currently contains this sentence:

> Questions can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, but each individual user may only vote once in each direction in the cycle.

Facti is that any user may only vote once in each direction on every question, not once per cycle.
So, can someone please remove "in the cycle"?

Motivated by this question:
[I cannot nominate a question for reopening twice? Even if it has been closed and reopened again?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278291/i-cannot-nominate-a-question-for-reopening-twice-even-if-it-has-been-closed-and)

Comment: For sure it has my +1, I thought it wasn't clear just to me because I'm not English speaker but what I understood there is opposite from what it is.

Comment: The "in the cycle" at the end is confusing at best. There is no need for it, so it should just be removed (and I am a native english speaker :) )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, ok, that was awkward. It now reads:

> Questions can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, but each individual user may cast at most one close and one reopen vote per question.