# Has the threshold for reopen vote expiry been changed?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

There is a question (closed by gold-tag hammer) that I wanted to be reopened. Right now it has only 18 views. I first voted (as did at least one other user) a couple of weeks ago. I noticed today that the votes had been reset, so I voted again.

According to [this 2011 post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97594/155659) reopen votes will only expire if the question has more than 100 views. According to [this 2014 post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278292/476716) I shouldn't be allowed to vote again.

The question wasn't reopened, so where did the reopen votes ago?

Comment: You can VTC (and through that, likely vote to reopen) [after 14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250453/332043)

Comment: Is it reasonable to make a reopen-closed request given the low views?

Comment: `[meta-tag:some-tag]` (ignore (sanity-checking): [meta-tag:support]). As for making a reopen-closed request, I'm not really sure.