# Are questions asking for feature sets of specific software versions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've seen a few questions that ask what features are available in a certain software release.  Are these questions on topic?  A while ago, I thought that I had read a criteria that recommended avoiding questions that could lead to list like responses, but I cannot find it now.  The reasoning was that they can become outdated or that they are more wiki like in their format and need to be maintained.

Examples:

- [What are the features added in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38060436/691711)
- [ECMAScript 6 features available in Node.js 0.12](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28388885/691711)

<strike>One of the questions is already on hold</strike>, but a [comment by drescherjm](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-features-added-in-c17#comment-63559917) points out:

> Yakk asked and answered the question. There were similar questions for the older standards.

Which leads me to believe that there is some confusion.  I just want a clear answer on whether or not these kinds of questions are or not on topic.

---

One thing is that these types of questions get upvoted **a lot** even though they seem off-topic.  These upvotes show that the question has value.  I'm not incredibly familiar with the Documentation Beta that [honk mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326951/691711#comment-361649) in their comment, but is one of the goals of Documentation to allow for more granular, wiki-oriented answers?  If that's the case, what should we do with questions that would be a better fit for Documentation while it is in beta?

Comment: Wouldn't such content be better off at [Documentation](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @honk Once it's available, maybe. I get the message it's still in private beta now though.

Comment: You are right that experience tells us list-style questions are not generally a good fit for Stack Overflow. However, that is just a guideline, not a hard rule. The C++ community has already set a ***strong*** precedent for its willingness and ability to maintain wiki-style questions. The most obvious example is the [C++ book list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242), but anything tagged [tag:c++-faq] is a good example. I see no reason to suppose that this one will be any different. In fact, this one doesn't even need to be maintained; the feature list for C++17 won't change.

Comment: @CodyGray actually is a hard rule: "There's nothing inherently wrong with your "I need a comprehensive list" question; **It's just that we specifically forgo asking these types of questions** because they are not a good fit for this type of Q&A site." [Robert Carantino](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/213575). The fact that SE went at length to just prohibit this kind of questions, makes it a hard rule. The fact that the c++ community could go away with it, doesn't mean that others should follow.

Comment: Robert is talking about recommendation questions. This is a rather different scenario, @Braiam. The reasons we ban recommendation questions do not apply in this case. The question doesn't ask for a large bucket of answers; it is not a poll; there are a limited number of entries; it is not subjective; etc. Robert and others use "list" as a shortcut for recommendation questions with *those* problems; they do not literally mean that any answer that includes a list of things makes the question off-topic. You're grasping at rules to follow blindly, instead of simply using your brain.

Comment: Alright, so it seems like consensus is that the C++ question is not too broad.  That's okay with me; this is the reason we have Meta.  I still have 2 questions I would like to discuss.  1. Why has the Node.js question been reopened?  It is a "moving target" like Yakk said was too broad in his answer.  2. Where is the line before a list question becomes too broad?

Comment: This whole meta question is a **shame**. Because the C++ community don't want their little snowflake to be closed they are imposing to the rest of the community their views, because if consensus is reached that those kind of questions are to be closed, they will not get away with it.

Comment: @Braiam Yeah, I still think the question should be closed.  However, I'd like to try to come to reasonable guidelines for list questions.  It would be nice to have a mod/SE employee come and tell us what should be done, but if that doesn't happen, we can always try to work it out ourselves.

Comment: @NobodyNada we kind of allowed this in the well forgotten past and decided to bury it along with all other dark history SO had... apparently some users are too young to remember.

Comment: @Braiam Being someone who's not involved in the C++ community here at all, and doesn't get along well with a number of the members of that community, I still think this question is appropriate for SO. Please do not substitute your condescension for an actual argument.

Comment: @NobodyNada: The line is simple: "Does it have a well defined scope or not?", both the links in the question satisfy that condition.

Comment: The single fact that this question has been closed and re-opened **4 times in the first 3 hours** of its existence is proof enough that we won't get a definitive verdict on this question's on-topicness.

Comment: @JesseGood The Node.js question is too broad according to Yakk's answer, because it is not about a specific version of Node.js, so it becomes outdated whenever there's an updated.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yeah.  Undo, Braiam, and I were discussing this in SOCVR, and I mentioned that "I remember when I first earned close vote privileges, I had a really hard time figuring out what was too broad. I looked all over Meta and the help center, but I could not find anything that explained exactly how broad was too broad. Eventually, I figured it out by looking at examples and asking people here in SOCVR whether certain questions were too broad or not, but I never really found objective guidance, and I think the lack of that is what's causing the problem here."

Comment: @NobodyNada: I thought `Node.js 0.12` as in the title made it clear it was a specific ver. Ignoring that, the objective guidance you are looking for *does not exist* as this is not an objective question to begin with. That is why we have meta to vote on these things.

Comment: @JesseGood ...Wow, how did I miss that?

Comment: Questions lilke this are requests for an offsite resource: *viz,* release notes, C+17 compatibility notes, etc, all of which are available from normative sources, which SO isn't.

Answer (score 36):

This answer will not be outdated, as it is a list of features for a major release, not a specific point release that will change every month.  Compilers will refer back to this standard version for a decade or more.

This answer is not too broad, because there were only 40-odd features added, out of 100s proposed.

It is true that "list all features" is not an appropriate question *when the answer would be too broad*.  I claim it isn't the request for a list, but rather lack of specificity in the request or broadness of the answer that is the problem.

It is easy for a "list all features" question to be too broad.  It can have unbounded scope (with a moving target).  The set of features can be simply too large.

It can even be too narrow, in that it might refer to a point release that will be obsolete in a month, and few tools will refer back to.

In this case, however, none of these apply.

It is useful without the links.  There were 100s of features proposed for C++17: knowing *which if them got into the standard*, and either their name or a very brief description, is useful information.  The links themselves contain the formal paper number for the feature in question (which is useful if they later go dead).

A complete comprehensive set of documentation might be better: but, like alternative stack exchange sites, the existence of another alternative is not evidence of it being off-topic.  And especially one in *beta*.

Comment: Is a serious oversight that that is not included anywhere in the spec (NEWS file, or changelog). SO wasn't meant to plug holes of someone documentation, but specific questions of practical programming problems. Having a list of new features is just entertainment. Fun to read and awe but by itself not practical

Comment: Has the committee decided on and published the final version of the C++17 spec?

Comment: @qpaystaxes it is "feature complete" according to the standardization team, not published.

Comment: While I believe 40 is way too much for SO answer, in this particular case it feels ok as list is well defined and not going to change significantly. (Usefulness of the question itself is somewhat questionable to me  - also I can see it serving as duplicate target to some "why XXXX does not compile in my ABC.123 compiler)

Comment: It is *extremely* practical. This is one of those cases where the sheer practicality of having this information available on Stack Overflow trumps the literal enforcement of rules about list-based questions. The rules are there to guide us towards high-quality content. The quality of this content stands on its own merits. We don't need heuristics to see whether or not it will work out, you can just look at the answer.

Comment: @CodyGray I ask you instead: do all information in the world have to be on SO? Then why would we have scope, close reasons and the like? Why the SE team feels that they need to create Documentation? Why?????

Comment: @Braiam Full on use documentation of every C++17 feature would be 10x-100x or more larger than the answer provided that lists the C++17 features and a brief description.  SO Documentation would be quite useful for that cluster of documents.

Comment: @Yakk "that lists the C++17 features" Are you arguing that SO should accept **lists** questions?! I prefer having no list at all than having to discuss *ad infinitum* each case individually. Something that cannot fit SO model *in any form possible* shouldn't be accepted in the first place.

Comment: All the information in the world obviously does not have to be on Stack Overflow. That is the epitome of a straw man argument. As for why the SE team feels they need to create Documentation, I honestly have no idea. I think it'll be a flop. If I was going to wager a guess, it'd be that companies gradually expand outward from their core business model, until they eventually have distracted themselves so much that their core business suffers. See also: Google builds its own phone hardware. Remember when they wanted to make Stack Overflow TV? Stupid ideas don't make questions off-topic. @Braiam

Comment: @CodyGray you are saying that "This is one of those cases where the sheer practicality of having this information available on Stack Overflow". Wouldn't be more practical to have concrete questions like "I'm updating my code to C++17 standards and I'm having trouble replacing <this removed feature>, how can I obtain the behavior of <removed featured>"? It has a useful practical answer. Having just a list of things that may or may not apply on my case isn't useful. Is just busywork.

Comment: What's the point in having rules for the community to follow, if they are flouted at will? Exceptions have already been made in the past for historical questions, no excuse for carrying that on now though.

Comment: The purpose of having rules, @Lankymart, is to *ensure quality*. If quality is being ensured through other means, then the rules become significantly less important. I, and others, would argue that the quality of this question and its answer are self-evident, and the typical concerns about its quality declining in the future are not relevant. Do you have an actual argument against that? Or do you just think that blindly following the rules should trump all other concerns, even once we've forgotten what the original purpose of those rules was?

Comment: @Braiam That's sort of what I'm saying, not exactly. I don't know why you need to paraphrase; I think I've made a fairly clear argument in the comments here. You made a reference at the end of your first comment to this not being practical: *"Fun to read and awe but by itself not practical."* I disagree with that. Having this information available is extremely practical. Are there other forms by which it could be presented? Yes. But you cannot name a question that can only be asked and answered in one way. Also, your example sucks. There are only three removed features, very rarely ever used.

Comment: @CodyGray *Steps away from the conversation...*

Comment: @CodyGray I'm tired, because you keep on defending the "general case" because you don't want *"your specific case"* to suffer. Why aren't you using the Node.JS question as example? Also, "Having this information **available** is extremely practical." Yeah, is practical in some sense, but before that was *already available **elsewhere***, do we really need to duplicate what was never hidden from plain view (and I still believe that a changelog is fundamental for any spec) that we need to mirror it on SO?

Comment: @Braiam: People have cast their votes and the verdict has been decided. There is no use continuing the argument.

Comment: "This answer will not be outdated, as it is a list of features for a major release". Of course it might become outdated. There will be drafts and there will be a final ISO standard. Until the final ISO standard is released, the answer is just (qualified) speculation.

Comment: @lundin yes, and it will be updated when the release is final if there sre any errors or omissions.  I do not intend to check until then.

Answer (score 28):

I think that those questions (and answers) are helpful and useful as long as:

- they are complete
- they are accurate

Note that unlike most similar questions, it is possible to answer them *objectively* and the answer is *definite* (it may require some tweaking within the first few hours/days, but no long-term effort to keep it up-to-date).

I would therefore argue that those are a *good fit* for SO.

Let's review the list of close reasons:

- *Duplicate*: obviously not
- *Off-Topic*: not *General Computing and Software*, not *Administration Related*, not about a *Recommendation or Off-site Resource*, not about a *Typo*, ...
- *Unclear*: it is very clear
- *Too Broad*: a complete answer fits within the post limit
- *Primarily Opinion-Based*: obviously not

*Too Broad* and *Off Topic* are probably the only ones worth arguing.

It does not match any canned reason proposed by *Off Topic* however, and even though *Too Broad* does mention that a question should *isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs* the exact limit of "few paragraphs" seems rather subjective (the only definite length limit is whether you can submit the answer) and existing very good answers have been known to be longer (such as [What is Branch Prediction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array)).

Comment: Absolutely agree, and I would like to add that the length is hardly an issue here, as these answers are basically a list of items, not a long essay on a very complex topic. It's not like you have to read a wall of text if you want to grasp the answer, as there's nothing to grasp. It's not like a passage can be unclear or incomplete: there are no passages! :-) Also, I think the record for the longest answer is the "It's only 10 pages on my monitor" one on [C++ move semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11540204/3982001). Now THAT is a long one, but still one of the best I've ever seen!

Comment: @FabioTurati: Good point about the difference between *length* and *complexity*.

Answer (score 7):

A good start, giving their wiki-nature, would be to actually mark them as Community Wiki.

From the OP:

> The reasoning was that they can become outdated or that they are **more wiki** like in their format and need to be maintained.

From a comment by Cody Gray:

> The C++ community has already set a strong precedent for its willingness and ability to maintain **wiki-style** questions.

Comment: This I agree with. How can anyone disagree with this, what would be wrong setting it to a community wiki?

Comment: @Lankymart I disagree. Yakk's answer was a considerable effort, and rewarding him with rep is what we have rep for. The point Matsemann quotes from the OP does not apply as C++ standards don't change, and late drafts don't change significantly. (Cannot judge the 2nd answer as I don't know the technology.)

Answer (score -8):

The problem with those questions is that they are way too broad:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

The C++ question is self-answered, so it was clearly intended to be a useful reference, [but that doesn't make it exempt from the rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278209/3476191).  Stack Overflow's Q&A format is not designed for a list of features; it's designed for a specific questions with specific answers.

[Stephen C's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388885/ecmascript-6-features-available-in-node-js-0-12#comment45115318_28388885) on the ES6 question does a good job summarizing the problem with list questions:

> "My hopes are that this question (and its answers) will become a comprehensive summary on what ES 6 features are now available to Node.js developers." - The chances are that it will simply become a disorganized mess ... that is just as out-of-date as all of the other resources!! Unless you 1) self answer and 2) take the time to curate the other answers into yours. If you are prepared to do that work, then it might be more appropriate to do it in a blog.

As Braiam pointed out, [list questions are explicitly off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/213575):

> There's nothing inherently wrong with your "I need a comprehensive list" question; It's just that we specifically forgo asking these types of questions because they are not a good fit for this type of Q&A site.
>
> Stack Exchange is well-suited to asking very specific questions that represent real problems you encounter in your day-to-day work. A big part of that process is asking very long-tailed questions; the kind where folks with specific expertise in the subject can propose the best possible answer, which is then voted on so the best possible answers rise to the top.
>
> Asking everyone to contribute to a large bucket of answers means that it stops being a question of specific expertise and becomes a "poll" of the community. For right or for wrong, answer start accumulating and people start voting on what they recognize as familiar, rather than vetting the relative merits of each answer. Often there are too many entries to even know what anyone is contributing anymore. It doesn't even matter; There's usually no expectation that any one answer will be better than any other.
>
> What I am saying is that the Big List™ breaks down the whole premise of why we created these sites in the first place — to vet and deem the information contained in the post as useful. Marking a question as "community wiki" does not take away from the inherent randomness of the discussion that becomes the thread.
>
> This isn't a personal attack on the value of asking these questions. There just might be — and that's a big "might" — a value in just having the list, but creating these "polls" is simply not what we do here.

While that answer is more for recommendation questions than objective lists, much of it is still applicable.  The C++ question isn't really a question, it's a changelog, which isn't what the site is designed for.  As Braiam explained in [his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327013/3476191), **even though it worked for this question, that doesn't mean it will always work, or that it fits the Q&A format**. If people start discussing C++17 features in the comments, the comments will become a mess.

Comment: The fact that the answer on the C++ question has almost doubled in size since posted and is still growing is a testament to that.(I did vote to close in case it gets reopened)

Comment: The thing that bothers me is that these types of questions get upvoted **a lot** even though they seem off-topic.  However, the upvotes show that the question obviously has value.  I'm not incredibly familiar with the Documentation Beta that @honk mentioned in their comment, but is that one of the goals of Documentation?

Comment: @NathanOliver Most of the doubling in size came from adding `##headers` and other formatting improvements.  Almost all of the rest from looking over the C++17 acceptance tests and adding a bullet point for each one.  At this point, about the only source of additional bulk would be from adding short descriptions of each added feature, or further formatting improvements.

Comment: Since it's self-answered, worst case scenario is the question gets closed but the answer will likely still get upvotes even if the question doesn't (i.e. it is a bad question, but a great answer)

Comment: "it's designed for a specific questions with specific answers." -- A question about what's different between C++14 and C++17 *is* a specific question with a specific answer. It requires a fairly long answer, but that does not make it a broad question. A broad question is one where basically no one can tell if an answer actually manages to fully answer it. That isn't the case here. I can tell *exactly* whether an answer manages to answer the question, as can you.

Comment: Note: if you read my previous comment as saying a nonsense question such as "What are the differences between the PS3 and Visual Basic?" wouldn't be too broad either, you're right, that is what I'm saying if it's clear the question is asked literally and it's clear that the OP understands that they are nothing alike. (Otherwise, it could be too broad since it's impossible to know what area of the OP's likely misunderstanding to focus on.) If asked literally, please keep in mind that I'm not saying it would be an okay question. That is already close-worthy for other more obvious reasons. :)

Comment: @hvd The "too broad" close reason doesn't say anything about not being answerable; it says "There are either too many possible answers, **or good answers would be too long for this format**.  Although the C++ question has only one correct answer, the correct answer is a long list of features; better for Wikipedia/a blog/C++ documentation than Stack Overflow.  I would consider 40 features too broad; the "too broad" reason says most questions should be answerable in a few paragraphs.  I guess that is where we disagree :)

Comment: @NobodyNada So are you saying the current answer is not a good answer, or it's too long? I'd say it's a good answer and given that it could become more than twice as large before hitting the post size limit, I don't see how you can really say it's already too long for SO.

Comment: @hvd It's a great answer; it's just not good for Stack Overflow's Q&A format, which is designed for concise answers to specific questions.

Comment: @NobodyNada Okay, then what's your standard for "too long for this format", if it's completely separate from the limit SO set for it?

Comment: A specific answer can include a list IMO. There are even some questions with answer lists spread over multiple answer (e.g. search for "undefined reference")

Comment: @hvd I think 3 is good limit before it becomes "a list of ...". There are indeed some exceptions (like [C++ books list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which is carefully maintained by tag's community, or some canonical duplicate targets like "What is NRE" for each language), but otherwise asking for "a list of ...." is generally too broad for SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I agree.  As far as I can tell, the Too Broad close reason isn't a fine line, but IMO this instance is way over the line.

Comment: Your argument about "too broad" does not make any sense. You quoted the portion that reads *"good answers would be too long for this format"*, implying that this rule is being violated. But the existing answer puts the lie to that implication. It fits within the character limit and works well with "this format". So this is just another case where someone wants Stack Overflow to become a "debug my code" site, rather than a world-class resource for programmers, a body of expert knowledge about practical programming problems. Use your brain as something other than a pattern matcher.

Comment: @CodyGray THANK YOU. "So this is just another case where someone wants Stack Overflow to become a "debug my code" site, rather than a world-class resource for programmers, a body of expert knowledge about practical programming problems." This sums up my current frustration with Stack Overflow perfectly.

Answer (score -15):

> Are questions asking for feature sets of specific software versions on topic?

No.

The Q&A format *works* because it restricts what you can do with it. It has been tested and proved, and we went through many issues trying to figure out how to do a Q&A format. The fact that *a handful* works, doesn't mean that it will in *every single case*. The pure Q&A format is the only thing that we can apply to anything and everything, doesn't matter the circumstances and be glad that it will work.

Examples of this working shouldn't be taken as precedent for others to follow. That someone was able to use a hammer to bolt a screw doesn't mean that most will be able to. Lets stick with using the right tool for the job instead of experimenting with stuff that will eat our behinds sooner or later.

To illustrate my argument, is different to ask "Tell me all new features of X" or "What changed in X between 1 and 2" than "How to do Y with X" or "This thing I was doing in X.1 doesn't work anymore in X.2". The former have no re-usability. You can't point people with real questions to them, unless they are asking the *exact* same thing, meanwhile with the later can be used as canonical questions to solve problems that programmers *really* experience. This lists are potential several Q&A's going to waste, because someone was too lazy/didn't care to ask the right questions instead. That's my main problem with them. A very expensive luxury question that nobody will use in something practical, to solve their issues and will set a bad precedent, instead of a potential 20~30 Q&A that can help several thousands to solve their problem.

P. S. : when I googled "register c++17 not working" as it was removed in the latest implementation of C++, I got some relevant results, one of them a SO post asking for, well, [a replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618008/replacement-for-deprecated-register-keyword-c-11), which is the kind of questions we should encourage. When I googled "node.js 0.12 how to use proxy" I got 0 relevant results. These questions ain't helping people to find solution to their problems.

Comment: How about the merits of these questions? It seems like your argument boils down to "questions like this could be bad" but you state nothing about these questions nor why they are bad.

Comment: @hichris123 [As Robert Cartaino explained](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/213575) and I mentioned in my answer, this sort of question can easily become a disorganized discussion, which SO tries to avoid.

Comment: @hichris123 if you find merits to the "questions" (I wouldn't call them questions in the sense of SE) that's your call. I prefer having them not, than having yet another way to shoot ourself in the foot.

Comment: But that's talking about questions where there is no correct answer, @NobodyNada. There is a specific answer that is correct to thesr question -- and when standards are finalised, it will not change.

Comment: @hichris123 that's still the wrong "question". Wouldn't be more effective asking "Why my register doesn't work anymore" with the answer "because *reasons*, here's how you can do the same thing now" rather than just a changelog.

Comment: That... doesn't seem to be a good argument, @Braiam. Most any question can provide a proxy for bad answers.

Comment: @hichris123 but at least you can objectively identify them as bad and we have grounds to nuke them from orbit. These kind of *things* (I should stop calling them "questions") doesn't allow us to do this process, because the constrains that applies to questions stop applying on these cases.

Comment: @hichris123 How much longer would you say this list would have to be before it is "too long for this format?"

Comment: This works better as an argument when you have an example of such a question with dozens of lazy answers. Not so much when addressing examples with a couple of detailed answers.

Comment: @Shog9 well, I can't provide those examples because they have been deleted since. But if I find one I will share it...

Comment: That itself is an argument for you earning 10K on SO then.

Comment: @Shog9 I know where this is going... When I find a question that I should answer, I will not tell you. You are going to answer it instead. BTW, I instead put an example in my answer of how this kind of content can be more useful.

Comment: FWIW, when I Google for exactly what you specified, "register c++17 not working", the second result I get is [Remove Deprecated Use of the `register` Keyword](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4340.html), which is very much relevant. The question we're talking about doesn't appear (nor do I know if it should -- it's not easy to tell right now if that's something someone would end up searching for), but I can't reproduce your "0 relevant results".

Comment: @hvd: I can reproduce it, searching on google.ca for that search string (without quotes, or with `register "c++17" not working`).  None of the results on the front page are even about C++.  Many of them are about Bill C-17 in the Canadian parliament.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. It's still on the first page on google.ca for me (in a private browsing session too, just in case that makes a difference), but it is a lot lower and very easy to miss.

Comment: I disagree with your point that "*You can't point people with real questions to them*".  You can't mark a question as a duplicate of this one, but you most certainly can give a short answer + a link to this.  (Or more likely, just the link to the relevant paper).  So it works great as a resource for people writing answers to specific questions.  Specific questions always include more than just "why is `register` not working", so answers will often have a bunch of other stuff to say about the OP's code and other confusions.  Questions from confused people usually don't make ideal dup targets.

Comment: @PeterCordes the short link should be [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4340.html) instead. Which is **the most canon reason for the feature being removed**. SO isn't meant to replace those channels, but to do what no channel has been able to do before.

Comment: @Braiam: That's the second part of what I said: that this works as a resource for answer-writers to find the links to the relevant papers, and to make sure they give correct info about when something changed in the language.  (e.g. from c++14 to c++17, rather than from c++11 to c++14.  Real questions will sometimes involve really old code compiled in c++17 mode, so it's helpful to be able to suggest compiling in c++14 mode to still get feature X, but without breaking code that uses removed / changed feature Y).

Comment: The example in your "P.S." is pretty disingenuous. You aren't going to find such a question because basically no one was using the `register` keyword in their C++11 or C++03 code. None of the mainstream compilers paid any attention to it, so it was *at best* a comment. Having it go away doesn't actually make any difference in the real world. It doesn't present a problem to be solved, it doesn't break any code other than superficially, so no one is asking about it. Delete the meaningless keyword and move on. If you didn't already do it 10 years ago. We don't need a question about this.