# If I can't determine whether a question is on- or off-topic, should I post it anyway?

Tags: discussion, scope

As in this recent case discussed: [Are questions asking for feature sets of specific software versions on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326951/are-questions-asking-for-feature-sets-of-specific-software-versions-on-topic) it seems to be the consensus that some areas of questions are depending on the answer for the question being on- or off-topic.

I was thinking that this is a general approach in the way as: "If your post COULD cause a broad list of answers, it is off-topic."

But the actual case was that @Yakk asked the question and answered it, being aware of the amount of bullet points required for the list. Which was considered as being fine in the ratio of information value divided by the amount of bullet points (or whatever decided here being on-topic for that manner).

So I'd like to know, would this have been a different thing, if some one asked this question, not planning to self-answer it, but just for being curious and not knowing the answer? Would it have been ok to ask it, as it is enough to assume that the post COULD be on-topic?

If this approach is ok, this is what I'd accept as answer.

**If it isn't (note for the following phrases, I'm not claiming it isn't)**, I'd like to know, why is it penalized if one too often asks off-topic questions?

If person A asked the same question for language x, where the feature count would be 40, while person B asked it for language y where the feature count would have been 1450. Both not being aware of the answers, why then the question person A asked is on-topic, while the question asked by person B isn't?

To clarify what I'm asking:

Is a questions on-topicness, depending on the answer or on the ways a answer could look? If so, it requires the asker to already know the answer, while if not, it would mean that kind of question, yakk asked isn't ok, since to decide the question being on topic in his case, is argued by the counted points of the answer.

Comment: I'm serious about this. before you all finaly vote to close this as beeing unclear, please give me a chance to clarify and let me know what exactly is unclear about this?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match your question, that's pretty unclear. What do you actually want to know? *"OK to ask it"* doesn't necessarily correspond to *"won't get downvoted/closed"*. If you have some other question you want to ask, but don't know if it's on topic, put *that* question in *this* question and get feedback on it. It seems pointless to discuss this in the abstract.

Comment: You can ask it, and risk getting downvoted and closed.  Of course, you could ask here for help.  People do often.  Simply introduce your question and your concerns about it, then add the body of the question so people on meta can read it.  We can then give you feedback on the question and hopefully save you some aggravation.

Comment: @Will: Thanks for your input. But then again people have to decide. And I'm simply asking for if this descisions actually are (in a big break down!)meant to be justyfied by is the post usefull when answered?

Comment: One might have asked "What are the new features C is bringing?" Another person is asking "What new features is c99 bringing?" Assuming both persons had just been curios, this would mean the kind, context and type of both questions would be the same. But one would lead to a feature list as big that it can describe the whole language while the other is finished with just a few handfull of bulletpoints. And I'm asking here if this is also to be considered when deciding a question beeing on or offtopic. Since both asked the same, I'm just curious if this is intended that one is and the other not.

Comment: Note that "just for being curious" is generally a bad reason to ask a question on SO as you likely will not be able to evaluate answers to suit your case (as you would not have one).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I aggree to that. But bad reasons for asking don't interfer with beeing on/off topic, do they?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38060436/revisions) of the question in case: [What are the new features in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17)
you'll see that the question has already been closed (and re-opened) **4 times in 3 hours.** That alone is proof enough that there is -at the moment- no consensus in the community about whether questions like this are on-topic or not.

You are not getting banned for asking just *one* question which turns out to be off-topic. So if there's just one question you are hesitating about, go ahead and ask it. You'll know the results soon enough. If you have *more* questions you are not sure about, please do more research - look at how similar questions have been received by the community, or check the discussions on Meta. You can even ask *on Meta* if a specific question would be on-topic or not ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing)), or that perhaps another Stack Exchange site is a better fit.

Comment: So you are saying, Everythink is ok to ask, as long it could also be answered by doing enough research? Note I'm not asking anything about that specific post here. but I'm asking how to apply the on /off topic rules. The rules say its to be avoided to ask questions that "could".... And I'm asking here when it is to be applyed such "could"? Can one argue, as long he knows the answer isn't a subset of what COULD happen. because he knows it doesn't? But then how to treat it if we assume the rules are mainly for designed for users asking questions they don't know the answer?

Comment: @Zaibis no, with 'research' I meant checking (e.g. on Meta, or by comparing similar questions) if a question is on-topic or not. I'll edit my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Ok thats more clear now. But my main point still is: If we say "Ok this is on topic as the list is limited by an fixed and absolute list, isn't this encouraging to ask questions in this way, as the answer could justify the question? And thereof my main question resulted: Is it maybe that way? Was I wrong all the time? and not the question allone actually is important for deciding about on/offtopic. and the answers could contribute to it too?. And thats simply what THIS metaOP is about.

Comment: @Zaibis good question, but I can't answer that. I haven't made my mind up yet what to think about the C++ list question, and I don't like the Meta discussion about it. It is just going into too many directions at once.

Comment: True point. but have you a idea, how I could make this OP more clear that it is that what I'm asking about?